# Strapi Invalid credentials, no email sent

Tags: next.js, strapi

I'm using Strapi with a NextJs frontend. Everything was working fine until today when I tried to start the app and I get `Invalid credentials` I'm positive that the email and password are correct. If I click the Forgot your password? and enter my email it says I will receive an email with the your password recovery link but I never receive the email.

Does anyone know why I getting this and how to fix it.

Comment: This sounds like something you need to contact Strapi over

Comment: I have posted on there forum, but never really get any response

Comment: must be an env db issue, double check if you are using multiple env instance , similar issue I have faced